# Subtract Energy values from previous row MySQL - Grafana panel

Tags: javascript, mysql, grafana

I'm working in a project with Node-Red, MySQL and Grafana.
In a Grafana panel I want to show the energy consumption by a day. The MySQL table record the accumulated energy by the end of every day, so I need to substract the selected row (selected by Grafana time filter) from previous. Doing that I will have the energy consumed/generated/excedent by that day.

See attached MySQL query:

```
SELECT
  TimeSTMP AS "time",
  KwhX1 AS "Consum",
  KwhFV1 AS "FotoVoltaica",
  KwhFECSA AS "Xarxa",
  KwhEXCD AS "Excedent"
FROM ContKwh
WHERE
  $__timeFilter(TimeSTMP)
ORDER BY TimeSTMP
```

[image: MySQL table capture]

Note-> KwhFecsa values are wrong. I've to fix it.

Best Regards,
Pau

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query